# Constraint with upper and lower limits of summation are as variables - How can I reformulate it?

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

As far as I know in the optimization models, the upper and lower limits of summation are parameters.

In my model now, there is a constraint with the upper and lower limits of summation are variables.
Is there any way to solve the problem? Is it possible to reformulate the constraint (look at the picture)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz3V9.png)

Comment: This is usually handled by additional binary variables. The precise formulation depends on the specific problem at hand.

Comment: Hey Erwin!  Thank you for ur answer. Do you suggest any scientific paper that contains an example of the process of adding binary variables?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a good reference off the top of my head.